# Loading initializers during assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to precompile the assets while deploying to  production environment.  I am also trying to automate it for first time installation on  a server using capistrano. It looks like none of the initializer's are getting loaded during the assets precompile process.

I am facing these two problems

1. For the first time installation I am generating a initializer file(initializers/freshinstall.rb) on the fly with the below content

   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

   so that precompile doesn't check the database which doesn't exist yet
2. I also have some vendor files,  and their locations are set in the asset pipeline, and are placed in separate initializer file initializers/vendor.rb

   MyApp::Application.config.assets.paths << "#Rails.root}/vendor/assets/images/xxxx" << "# {Rails.root}/vendor/assets/images/xxxx/helpers" 
   MyApp::Application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/xxxx"
   MyApp::Application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/yyyy" << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/images/yyyy"

When capistrano runs the assets precompile task, its not able to find the vendor paths or stopping it from looking into the database. This brings me to a conclusion that the initializer's are not getting loaded. After going through some stackoverflow questions. I even added a railtie to config/application.rb

```
module AssetsInitializers
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "assets_initializers.initialize_rails",
                :group => :assets do |app|
      require "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/freshinstall.rb"
      require "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/vendor.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

But I still don't see any initializers getting loaded. Can I get some info on the internals of the boot process of an rail application, and also why the initializers are not getting loaded during the assets precompile process.

Some documentations would be really helpful to understand this. The Rails documentation is very minimal with respect to railtie and the initializer method.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to figure out how to do it. This works for my single server capistrano deployment. Below is the capistrano task for my new_deploy on to a fresh server.

```
set :fresh_install, false
task :new_deploy do
    set :fresh_install,true
    deploy.setup
    #The assets:precompile process is part of the deploy.update. Before the precompile process, we will create database.
    deploy.update
    deploy.migrate
    run_seed
    #load unicorn server
  end
```

Dont do any configuration setting mentioned below

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false  # no need of this in application.rb
```

Instead just before assets:precompile create your database

```
before "deploy:assets:precompile" , "yourapp:create_database"
```

See that you check if the fresh install flag is set, then only create the database.This method will also be called during regular deploy when ever you are updating the server with latest revision. During that scenario fresh_install flag will be false.

```
desc 'Create a new database'
  task :create_database, :roles => :app do
     if fresh_install 
        run "cd #{release_path}; bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
      end
  end
```